# Vb.net ms access app coding creating new table

Tags: vb.net

I have created a new Ms Access table with vb.net 12, how could I automatically name the new tables I create to the "Current Day Date"

Comment: Do you mean you have created an ADOX `Catalog` and added a new `Table` object to the Catalog? What does *name the new tables I create to the "Current Day Date"* mean? Do you want to name a new Table, e.g., `20210403`? Are you doing this in VB.Net or VBA? With what code?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more and add some clarity around what specifically you’re trying to do, along with what you’ve tried so far and where you’re getting stuck in those attempts?

Comment: Don't create new tables every day. Put the data in the same table with the date in a column

Comment: I am creating a temperature recording database application with Vb.net 12 windows forms Application for a church. Each Sunday members get checked temperatures and get recorded. I want the application to be able record once the name of a member and then regularly on Sundays add temperatures to the members info with new date. Member details ; Full name and temperature

Answer (score 0):

! expected layout
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhkPP.jpg)

Hi guys, is there a VB.net froms application access database code that enables me to add new column to an already created table in VB.net.

I am building a temperature registration app so I want it to be able to add new column and possibly name it as to the "current day date"

Comment: Sorry it's actually a question